# Cannot make a static reference to non-static method issue

Tags: java

I have overriden the method toString() in class Person, but i cant use it in my main method - "Cannot make a static reference to non-static method toString() from the type Object"

```
class Person {
private String name;
private int id;

public Person(String name,int id) {
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    String result = "Name: "+this.name+" ID: "+this.id;
    return result;
   }
}

public class Testing {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Person person = new Person("Ivan",1212);
    System.out.println(toString()); // Cannot make a static reference to non-static method 

   }
}
```

How can i fix this ?

Comment: omg.... sorry fot the stupid question...

Comment: Paste the title of your question in google, and read one of the hundreds of returned pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
System.out.println(person.toString());
```

`toString` method is a non-static method, meaning it is related to a specific instance.

When you want to call it, you need to call it on a specific `Person` instance.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to call a non-static method from a static context (in this case, your main method). To call the `Person` object's `toString` method, you'll need to do `person.toString()`.

Sometimes thinking of our code as English helps us make sense of it. The English for this statement is "Convert the person to a string.". Let's turn this into code.

Person maps to the `person` object we've created. "to a string" maps to the `toString()` method. Objects and verbs (methods) are separated by periods in Java. The complete code for the English above is `person.toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the method like that, you should use the referece "person" !

```
System.out.println(person.toString());
```

Comment: No need to call `toString()` here

Comment: Yes you're right, but i put it because I don't like to confuse user2976091

Answer (score 0):

`toString(....)` is a member method of the `Person` Class. That means you can invoke it via an object instance of the class. So, you need to invoke `person.toString()` instead of `toString()` in `System.out.println(....);`